# Overclocked GPU quantum problem

Tags: gpu, overclocking

I overclocked my nVidia GPU, and now I get it to be much faster, but after a ~40% overclock, I start getting "mistakes" on the screen, like wrongly coloured pixels, glitches and the sort. Temperature is still within limits, as I added extra coolers. So my question is: is this a permanent problem which is damaging the GPU or is only something related to the intrinsic quantum mistake rate of processing calculations?

Thanks for your opinion :-)

Comment: You could always undo the overclock setting and see if you are still getting glitches, etc.

Comment: True, and I don't see anything strange when I undo the overclock. Problem is that I'm worried on the long term damages, since I'm goign to run a GPU cluster like this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's a voltage problem. Overclocking a card will result in a higher power consumption (higher temperature) and since the card isn't built for that, at some point it can't keep the voltage level and it will drop, leaving you with graphical glitches.

Normally, this shouldn't damage the card...but I wouldn't bet on it.

If you want to overclock it even higher, you'll have to do some soldering to increase the voltage within the card.